# Render a blade template var from a MySql loaded script

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have 2 tables in a database and I need data from both for rendering.

1. The first table contains HTML code, that should be rendered:

   ```html
   <h1 style="{!! $color !!}">hello world</h1>
   ```
2. The second table contains a color to render, such as: red

To clarify, I'm loading HTML code that should be rendered from the database. This HTML code contains some other blade snippet that should be evaluated when it is rendered. The problem is that this code is not evaluated. Instead, the raw instruction is outputted.
Thus, I'm seeing `{!! $color !!}` instead of the value `red` at the position of this instruction.

I'm currently using the following snippet to render the HTML content, this variable has the blade instruction along with some other HTML in it:

```
{!! $html->myHtmlCode !!}
```

---

- Current output: hello world (normal color)
- Desired output: hello world (red font)

What can I do to achieve the desired output?

Comment: I'm assuming you have some variable, that contains blade code. You want to evaluate the contents of this variable as blade code. I'm not quite sure if this is possible, without using hacky code at least.

Comment: Yes, in the MySQL database I have this value "<h1 style="{!! $color !!}">hello world</h1> " and I want it to render "red" instead of $color, so...no hopes?

Comment: fyi, `style="red"` is not valid

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that it is not rendering RED, it is rendering the instruction = {!! $color !!}

Comment: I'm afraid you have to find some other solution. You may use `view(...)->render()` as PHP code (wrapped in a PHP code block) in blade to render another view, but it must be rendered from a view file.

In your case it might be possible to replace the blade code with some placeholder. Once you fetched the data out of the database, do a replacement on this placeholder with the desired value inside PHP itself. Render that result in blade.

This removes the need of evaluating blade code from a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help. Try using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php) php class. you can load your code comming from MySQL

```
<h1 style="{!! $color !!}">hello world</h1>
```

This will create a document node and will let you of modify as you want. Aply styles for example. But you have to do it before render your page. Hope this help.